# Hook in NUnit or SpecFlow when a test fails

Tags: nunit, specflow

So I am using SpecFlow with NUnit for developing end-to-end acceptance tests of a web application with Selenium. One of the things we do to try to gauge the nature of a failure, is to take a screenshot of the browser whenever a regression test fails. I am currently doing it by wrapping each of my tests in try/catch blocks, and taking the screenshot in the catch with Selenium then, rethrowing the exception. This works, but it makes the tests messier and more tedious.

Is there a way in either NUnit or SpecFlow to call a hook when any test fails, before any teardown method is called?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the ScenarioContext to detect if a scenario generated an error.

```
ScenarioContext.Current.TestError
```

If not null, then an error occurred. You can check this and use it to determine whether to take a screenshot or not. You can see an example on [SpecFlow's documentation reference](http://www.specflow.org/documentation/ScenarioContext/).

You can also make this an AfterScenario Hook so you do not need to have the try/catches everywhere. It would simply check every test at the end to see if an error occurred and whether to create a screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to take screenshot on Nunit(3.0+) failure , you can use below

```
    [TearDown]
    public void AfterScenario()
    {
        if (TestContext.CurrentContext.Result.Outcome.Status == TestStatus.Failed)
        {
           // code to take screenshot based on framework you are using)
        }
    }
```

please note down specflow has [AfterScenario] and Nunit has [Teardown] where you should be putting this code

for latet specflow version (3.9) you would have to use, dependency injection in your case class like below to get the **scenariocontext**

```
    private readonly ScenarioContext scenarioContext;
    // constructor 
    public YourClassName(ScenarioContext scenarioContext)
    {
        scenarioContext = scenarioContext;
    }

    [AfterScenario]
    public void  TearDown()
    {
    if (scenarioContext.ScenarioExecutionStatus.ToString().Equals("TestError"))
     {
          // screenshot code
     }
    }
```